# Why this returned function being called without any action to its value?

Tags: javascript, function

Look at the following code:

```
function doNotCallMe(){
    alert("Otherwise the world will be destroyed!");
}

function getNotCallable(){
    return new function() {
        alert("Attention!");
        doNotCallMe(); 
    };  
}

var not_callable = getNotCallable();
```

The browser shows the alerts, which it shouldn't be. Why? How to fix?

Comment: You can remove `new` from `return new function() {`.

Comment: Which alert are you talking about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
return function() { ... }
```

is what you want instead.

All functions in JavaScript will act as object constructors when used with operator `new`; so you're defining an anonymous function, and then invoking it through `new`.

Comment: Is that `var obj = new afunction()` do the same as `var obj = {}; afunction.apply(obj,[]);`?

Comment: That's a part of it, but not the whole of it. As the most important part, it misses the prototype assignment. Read up on JavaScript OOP; a good intro can be found at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript).